# Inject array into Controller with Service Container

Tags: laravel, laravel-service-container

I want to provide some default settings to a controller when it is instantiated. My end goal is to provide a dummy object for testing which I can use with `registerPaymentMethod` on my controller To that end I thought I could provide these via the service container:

```
public function registerPaymentMethod($name, $class)
{
    $this->methods[$name] = $class;
}
```

I was unsure whether to use `->bind` or `->singleton` here.

```
$this->app->singleton('CheckoutController', function($app)
{
    $controller =  new CheckoutController();
    $controller->registerPaymentMethod('stripe', StripeCheckoutMethod::class);
    return $controller;
});
```

When I come to call on my `$methods` array, it is empty. For example the following is called from a route:

```
public function getCheckoutMethods()
{
    dd($this->methods); //gives []
}
```

As stated my goal is to inject a dummy object into the controller so I can test the functionality of the controller without calling on a specific `CheckoutMethod` (which `StripeCheckoutMethod` implements).

```
public test_something()
{
   $this->app->singleton('CheckoutController', function($app)
   {
        $controller = new CheckoutController();
        $controller->registerPaymentMethod('dummy_method', MyDummyCheckoutMethod::class);
        return $controller;
   }

   //test things knowing that CheckoutController now has a 'dummy_method'
}
```

Any guidance appreciated!

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container#binding-primitives ?

Comment: Thanks I did look at this. My answer was a stupid mistake eventually!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was an omission my part. I should explicitly provide a fully qualified class:

```
$this->app->bind('App\Http\Controllers\CheckoutController', function($app)
{
    $controller =  new CheckoutController();
    $controller->registerPaymentMethod('stripe', StripeCheckoutMethod::class);
    return $controller;
});
```

or

```
use App\Http\Controllers\CheckoutController;

$this->app->bind(CheckoutController::class, function($app)
{
    $controller =  new CheckoutController();
    $controller->registerPaymentMethod('stripe', StripeCheckoutMethod::class);
    return $controller;
});
```

Also note that I used `bind` here rather than `singleton`